# How can I make unselectable TextBox with enable Scroll?

Tags: wpf, textbox, readonly

I want to make ***unselectable TextBox with enabled ScrollBar*** in WPF.

If I set **IsReadOnly=True**, it can scroll but selection of text is possible.

And if I set **IsEnabled=True**, it is unselectable but scrolling gets disabled.

**IsHitTestVisible=True** is also unselectable, disabled scroll.

How can I make unselectable, enabled scroll TextBox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'IsHitTestVisible' leads textbox to inactive and you can't modify the content. I Hope below code will meet your requirement

WPF:

```
<ScrollViewer Width="120" Height="50">
        <TextBox x:Name="txBox" SelectionBrush="Transparent" ContextMenu="{x:Null}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="How can I make unselectable TextBox with enable Scroll?"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

if you want to restrict copying text from textbox use below code additionally.

Code behind:

```
private void TxBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txBox.SelectedText.Length > 0)
        {
            txBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }
```

Good Day :)

Comment: Oh my god !  SelectionBrush="Transparent" !!! Goooood idea !  Thanks a lot !!! I can fix it ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `IsHitTestVisible=false` and wrap the TextBox with a ScrollViewer

```
    <ScrollViewer Width="100" Height="50">
        <TextBox IsHitTestVisible="False" TextWrapping="Wrap">asjdla jksad lkjasd jd kla sljas kdj ksald jksad ksalj dlasj lkajs ljka sajksd</TextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```